# 2004 Hyundai Sonata: Brake light diagnosis

Tags: brakes, tail-lights, brake-light

The neighbor's brake's lights won't turn off: the fuse has to be pulled to avoid draining the battery.  He asked me to check the fuse and it tested good (continuity test).

- What is the procedure to test / isolate fault?
- Is there a brake sensor that could be 'stuck'?

Will do my best to answer any questions that aid diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

Most common fail is the switch either failed inside or stuck on with dirt.

Less common but has happened is a short with another live wire but then pulling the fuse would not be the cure.

So, check the switch on the brake pedal.

Comment: I agree with this, I've also seen objects or even the carpet getting wedged, preventing the switch from opening.